# Can a powered-down robot be repaired at a workshop?

Tags: robo-rally

When a robot is powered down it loses all damage tokens, but can collect new ones by laser fire.

If a damaged, powered-down robot is standing on a workshop at the end of its turn: Does it lose one damage token?
Is the same answer also true for getting option cards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, robots can still receive damage tokens while powered down. From [Page 5 of the rulebook](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/roborally.pdf) under **Power Down**:

> Other robots can push a powered-down robot, and the robot can still be damaged (such as by laser fire), Because of that, a robot that’s powered down may receive new Damage tokens during the turn

Yes, you still repair damage and collect option cards. (Page 5)

> The robot doesn’t receive or execute Program cards and doesn’t move while powered down, but board elements still affect it.

And page 8:

> **Repairs & Upgrades** - Robots on a single-wrench space discard 1 Damage token. Robots on a crossed wrench/hammer space discard 1 Damage token AND draw one Option card.

**Note**: My answer is based upon the most recent rules available from Wizards of the Coast. There seems to be some differences between [older printings](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/736692/different-rules-version-1994-and-2005) of this game. This [thread claims](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/8313174#8313174) to link to a text version of the [1994 rules](http://globetrotter-games.com/index.htm?E&game/rules/eRobRal1.htm) that indicate:

> A powered-down robot is completely shut down--it can't fire weapons, tag checkpoints, or update its archive location, nor can it acquire or use option cards. Powered-down robots don't move under their own power (they receive no program cards), but they may be moved by pushers, gears, and conveyor belts. They may also be pushed by other robots and shot at by lasers

Comment: Am I right that the updated rules (which are the ones that I have as well) do not explicitly state that powered-down robots cannot shoot their laser?

Comment: The quoted rule about repaired damage doesn't sound right to me.  'Board Elements,' to me, classifies anything that moves the robot, not the wrench/workshop squares.  This is because its supposed to be challenging to land on that spot again and again to collect option cards...not so easy as to do it once every other turn for free.

Comment: The new rules seem fair - you get repaired, but you cannot take any option cards. And if you powered down and you still have damage that needs to be repaired, chances are you need it - so it seems fair.